# variations in 4-fold cross-validation coefficients

Tags: cross-validation, gini

What does it mean when one of 4-folds Gini coefficient has a low number. For instance 83%, 84%, 85% and **75%**?

Is this variation is in a normal range?

Can it be caused by outliers?

Does it worth researching why one fold is performing worst.

I am new to the material so I apologize if the question has some issue.

Comment: It’s not possible to give a universal answer about whether this is in a “normal” range - it depends on the model and the data. Still, if you ever find anything you find unusual, it’s good to understand why it happens.

Comment: thanks @Arya. can it be related to presence of outliers?